# Handling props in higher order components in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing props in Login component and that component is wrapped in another component "FormHandle" which itself is passing props, in React using TypeScript. But in Login component throws the following error:

```
 [ts] `Property 'loginLabel' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<(Anonymous class)> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNo...'.`
```

The interface of Props in LoginForm is :-

```
interface ILoginformProps {
  //below props coming from login component
  loginLabel: string;
  passwordLabel: string;
  // below props coming from form handler Heigher order component
  handleChange: () => void;
  handleSubmit: () => void;
}
```

Now when I call LoginForm as :-

```
<LoginForm loginLabel="Login" passwordLabel="password"/>
```

It is giving the above error.

The Code for the Wrapper is :-

```
import * as React from "react";

// This higher order component wraps FORM functionality
function HandleForm(Form: any, callAction: (state: object) => void) {
  return class extends React.Component<object, {}>{
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = {};
    }

    handleChange(e: any) {
      const { value, name } = e.target;
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e: any) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let state = this.state;
      callAction(state);
    }

    render() {
      return <Form {...this.props} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />;
    }
  };
}

export default HandleForm;
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that does the wrapping ? The HOC itself if it's something custom would be useful.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, i had added the Wrapping code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a bit of generic magic to the HOC in order to forward the prop types to the wrapped component. Also the wrapped component props need to have the fields `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` while the resulting component needs to have these fields excluded (since they are provided by the HOC). To get this to work we can use `Exclude` to get only the keys that are not `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` and use `Pick` to pick them from the original props:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface HandleFormProps {
  handleChange: (e: any) => void;
  handleSubmit: (e: any) => void;
}

// This higher order component wraps FORM functionality
// TProp  will be the props of the passed in component
function HandleForm<TProp extends HandleFormProps>(Form: React.ComponentType<TProp>, callAction: (state: object) => void) {
  // We return a component that pick only the properties that are not provided by the HOC
  return class extends React.Component<Pick<TProp, Exclude<keyof TProp, keyof HandleFormProps>>, {}>{
    constructor(props: any) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = {};
    }

    handleChange(e: any) {
      const { value, name } = e.target;
      this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e: any) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let state = this.state;
      callAction(state);
    }

    render() {
      return <Form {...this.props} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />;
    }
  };
}

// Usage 
interface ILoginformProps {
  //below props coming from login component
  loginLabel: string;
  passwordLabel: string;
  // below props coming from form handler Heigher order component
  handleChange: () => void;
  handleSubmit: () => void;
}
// Sample component, add your own implementation 
class LoginComponent extends React.Component<ILoginformProps> {

}

const LoginForm = HandleForm(LoginComponent, () => { });
let d = <LoginForm loginLabel="Login" passwordLabel="password" />
```

Comment: Thanks, @Titian, your solution approach was useful.